# Finding the residues of the following poles

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

We have the following function
$$\phi(z)=\frac{z^2-4z+4}{\sin(\pi z)}.$$
I know the poles are $z=n$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, but how do I find the residues of them all at once?

Comment: Hint: First compute the residues of $\frac{1}{\sin(\pi z)}$.  Then, involve the numerator.

Comment: @MichaelBurr How would I find the residues of that? Just the $-1$th coefficient of the Laurent series?

Comment: @b00nheT Do you mean that is how I find the residue of $1/\sin(\pi z)$? And how do I find the residues of $(z^2-4z+4)/\sin(\pi z)$?

Answer (score 1):

One may write, as $z \to n$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\sin(\pi z)}&=\frac1{(-1)^n\pi(z-n)+O((z-n)^3)}
\\\\&=\frac{(-1)^n}{\pi(z-n)}\frac1{1+O((z-n)^2)}
\\\\&=\frac{(-1)^n}{\pi(z-n)}+O(z-n),
\end{align}
$$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{z^2-4z+4}{\sin(\pi z)}&=(z^2-4z+4)\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{\pi(z-n)}+O(z-n) \right)
\\\\&=((z-n)^2-(2n-4)(z-n)+n^2-4n+4)\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{\pi(z-n)}+O(z-n) \right)
\\\\&=\frac{(-1)^n(n^2-4n+4)}{\pi(z-n)}+O(1),
\end{align}
$$ thus the residue is

> $$
> \text{Res}(\phi;n)=\frac{(-1)^n(n^2-4n+4)}{\pi}.
> $$